# Adding a Dialog box to a column description

Tags: 2013, list, column, modal-dialog

I was wondering if it is possible to add a pop up/Dialog box to column description? I would like to concerve space by allowing the user a "view more option" with a more detailed description of the list item. Currently there is only a 1-2 line prompt, but it is desired to have a longer more detailed description. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: I would be happy if it just linked to an internal or external site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using **Client Side Rendering**. I believe following references will help you to customize your form.

- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms)
- [Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)
- [Client Side rendering at PnP](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Branding.ClientSideRendering)

There is great tool for [SharePoint CSR Live Edit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to find and replace the html of your description. Add a content editor web part to your new and edit forms. This code will alert the full description.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tbAllFields").html($("#tbAllFields").html().replace("This is my description and this is the part I want to hide.", "This is my description and ... <a onclick='javscript:alert(\"This is my description and this is the part that I want to hide.\");'>more</a>"));
   });
</script>
```